# Calculate difference between quarter periods in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know the "difference" between two quarters.

```
>>> a = pandas.Period('2021Q1', freq='Q')
>>> b = pandas.Period('2021Q2', freq='Q')
>>> c = pandas.Period('2021Q4', freq='Q')

>>> c - b
<2 * QuarterEnds: startingMonth=12>

>>> b - a
<QuarterEnd: startingMonth=12>
```

Not sure how to interpret the result of this subtractions.

Here I would expect `True`.

```
>>> (c - b) == 2
False

>>> (c - b) > 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.QuarterEnd' and 'int'
```

What is `QuarterEnd` exactly and how do I handle that a save way?

I want to have the difference in quarters, not in days, years, hours or something else. In fact I just want to know if one quarter follows the other. If the difference is greater then 1 then it do not follows.

Comment: to get the quarter diff: `(c.quarter - b.quarter) == 2`.  I don't know why (Period - Period) returns `QuarterEnd` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the difference between two quarters in this way:

```
def diff_q(a: Period, b: Period) -> int:
    return (a - b).n
```

Examples:

```
>>> diff_q(pd.Period('2022Q2', freq='Q'), pd.Period('2021Q1', freq='Q'))
5
>>> diff_q(pd.Period('2022Q2', freq='Q'), pd.Period('2021Q3', freq='Q'))
3
>>> diff_q(pd.Period('2022Q2', freq='Q'), pd.Period('2022Q2', freq='Q'))
0
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit the purpose of the `QuarterEnd` class. The docu do not help me understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't why the difference is `QuarterEnd`, but for your second question
you can use a custom function like this (maybe add some assert statements as well):

```
a = pd.Period('2021Q1', freq='Q')
b = pd.Period('2021Q2', freq='Q')
c = pd.Period('2021Q4', freq='Q')

def get_quarter_diff(t1, t2):
    return (t1.year - t2.year) * 4 + (t1.quarter - t2.quarter) 

get_quarter_diff(c, a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
3
```